# Multiple Activities Workout and Recovery

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

I just bought my first Apple Watch (Series 7) and headed to the gym to track my workout. It's fair to say I expected and actually made a mess as I was trying to figure out how to do this!

It does not help that my workout seems a bit more complex than what the Apple Watch can either handle or communicate via its UI.

My workout is basically this. Over a period of 3 minutes, do the following:

- 200m of indoor running
- 15kcal of skiing (Skierg)
- Up to the 3 minute mark, rowing.
- 90 seconds cooldown.
- Repeat 6 times.

I did try to follow the Apple Guide on how to [Use the Workout app on your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204523).
Here are a few of the issues I faced and how I messed up the workout either by not tracking it completely or by having to mentally juggle the current set and time.

- I couldn't tell how much time I had left in a set. I started a workout with 200m of indoor running. Tapped the New button to add the skiing however the time started tracking from 0.
- Adding the rowing as an "open" activity, then stopping the workout once I hit the 3 minute mark, did not record the rowing.
- Given the overall time (3 minutes) of the set wasn't recorded, I couldn't tell how much time I had to row without keeping track in my head of the previous activities.
- Since rowing was an "open" activity, I didn't get an alert when I was at the 3 minute mark. I realise that I can setup a "timed" activity based on the seconds I calculated I need to but the amount varies, creating a new custom timed activity each time does get in the way.
- I couldn't tell what set I was in. I know that I can double tap to mark a segment. My understanding is that this is per activity rather. Not sure how to mark a segment across the 3 activities.

Every time I finished a "set", I would end the activity and start a 90 seconds timer before starting again. I know now that I can use a "cooldown" activity. Seemingly you can't have a cooldown based on seconds (i.e. 90) but hours/minutes instead. In any case, would adding a cooldown period be the way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help!